# Query returns a field which holds no data

Tags: mysql

I have a query which does some comparisons across two tables and returns the minimum out of those results.

The problem is, I'm using Inner Joins and if there is no matching row aka the row does not exist, the field is blank.

I'm wondering if theres a way to alter it so if the row does not exist it'll still return a value.

This is my query:

```
SELECT MIN(quantity_per_one * 5 < quantity) AS has_enough
FROM costs
INNER JOIN user_ingredients USING (IngredientID)
```

If the user has no ingredient the row does not exist, this causes `has_enough` to equal nothing. How can i adjust it so it'll be `0`

Table structure:

`table for costs`

```
//note there can be multiple ingredients per materialID
ID | materialID | IngredientID | quantity_per_one
 1 |     5      |     6        |       60
 1 |     5      |     3        |       10
```

---

`table for user's available ingredients`

```
ID | UserID | IngredientID | quantity
1 |    2    |     6        |    100
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I don't know what you mean ? It's MYsql if that answers the Q @GoatCO

Comment: @Dave Are you using SQL Server?, MySQL?, Oracle?, Postgres?....and also tell us the version. Oh, and you can also tell us to which table do those columns belong to

Comment: Ohh ok im using MySQL. Ill post table and fields in question.

Comment: RDBMS = Relational Database Management System = SQL Server, MySQL, etc.

Comment: @Lamak table structures added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MIN(quantity_per_one * 5 <= quantity),0) AS has_enough
FROM costs
LEFT JOIN user_ingredients USING (IngredientID)
```

Update:

You need a CASE Statement to do what you're after:

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN quantity IS NULL THEN 0
                               ELSE quantity_per_one * 5 < quantity
                          END) as 'has_enough'
FROM costs c
LEFT JOIN user_ingredients ui
  ON c.IngredientID = ui.IngredientID
```

Demo:  [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e5d8/23/0)

Comment: It will be if you use `COALESCE`instead of `ISNULL`. (Well, for the query to be agnostic, you should also use `ON costs.IngredientID = user_ingredients.IngredientID`

Comment: May i ask what `COALESCE` does not seen that used before.

Comment: `COALESCE` returns the first non-NULL value from a series, in this case, if `quantity_per_one` is `NULL` it returns `0`.

Comment: @GoatCO hmm after further testing it seems to return `1` even if the user does not have the ingredient in the table =/

Comment: I don't fully understand your initial query, with a <= inside the MIN() function.

Comment: its checking if the user `quantity` has enough of the cost `quantity_per_one * order total`, granted i should remove the `=` but that shouldnt cause the issue as the row doesnt even exist in the db but it returns 1

Comment: @GoatCO i added example data to the question which shows it should return `0`